# How to transform chess moves from many lines in 1 line only?

Tags: pear, chess

I have big pgn chess database with 5000+ games. I want transform every game written in 4-10 lines in 1 long line only. Can you help me to do that? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Here is link of my database games 

https://www.sendspace.com/file/rc2jqp

Comment: @wp78de I think this can solve previous problem about signing every white or black move.  Moves of game written in 1 line instead many line!
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking many hours, here is command line:

```
   perl -00 -ne "s/([\h][\r\n])/\ /g;print;" games.pgn>oneline.pgn
```

Problem solved